# How to show Emoji like skype in ios sdk

Tags: ios, emoji, uikeyboardtype

I am creating Chat Application. I want enable emoji symbols like skype in my application even thought the 
Settings -> General ->Keyboard -> Add New Keyboard ->Emoji
Was not enabled in device.

[image: keyboad image]
I need to display the emoji  like the above image. Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: Skype uses a full custom option, they even made a custom textView (maybe webview) to render the emoticons.

Comment: is there is any other way to add emoticons ?

Comment: Other then using the default emtoicons no, you will have to build it all your self.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Directly assign emoji characters in control.

I have used \ue231 characters emoji as bullet in UITextView and UILabel.

lbltest.text=@"\ue231 Check this out!";

You can refer [this link](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/) for getting supported emoji characters.

Answer (score 2):

You try them. I think it useful.

http://code4app.net/ios/custom-emoji-keyboard/51395bee6803fa8427000000
http://code4app.net/ios/TSEmojiView/501229bd6803faa052000000

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.